# Fixing of an XPath predicate for use in XML::Twig

Tags: perl, xpath, xml-twig

I'm trying to write a subroutine in Perl that will delete a given node in XML when provided with the text values of some of the children nodes.

Given XML like:

```
<Path>
  <To>
    <My>
      <Node>
        <ChildA>ValA</ChildA>
        <ChildB>ValB</ChildB>
        <ChildC>ValC</ChildC>
      </Node>
    </My>
  </To>
</Path>
<!-- A lot of siblings follow... -->
```

The XPath expression I'm using is essentially:

```
/Path/To/My/Node[ChildA="ValA" and ChildB="ValB" and ChildC="ValC"]
```

When I'm trying to run my script, I'm getting an error like:

```
Error in XPath expression
/Path/To/My/Node[ChildA="ValA" and ChildB="ValB" and ChildC="ValC"] at 
ChildA="ValA" and ChildB="ValB" and ChildC="ValC" at Twig.pm line 3353
```

I'm at a loss for this and am looking for suggestions. I've tried googling around, but I can't find working examples of trying to use predicates like this in `XML::Twig`. I don't know if the problem is in my XPath syntax or how I'm using `XML::Twig`.

For good measure, I've also tried:

```
/Path/To/My/Node[ChildA/text()="ValA" and ChildB/text()="ValB" and ChildC/text()="ValC"]
```

No luck with that either. What is the solution?

Comment: are you using this expression with `findnodes` or as a trigger for a `twig_handlers` ? `findnodes`, as mentioned by Sean, will allow you to use all of XPath, provided you use XML::Twig::XPath. The predicates for triggering handlers are more limited, you would need to have a handler for `Node` that tests the values of the children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the test, `Node` is the context node, so you have to say:

```
/Path/To/My/Node[./ChildA="ValA" and ./ChildB="ValB" and ./ChildC="ValC"]
```

This works for me in a short test program that uses `XML::XPath`.

EDIT: Sorry, I'm not so familiar with XML::Twig, and I made an incorrect assumption about its XPath capabilities.  According to the documentation, it supports only an "XPath-like" syntax that doesn't rise to the level of complexity of your example.  However, if you use `XML::Twig::XPath` instead of `XML::Twig`, you get the full XPath engine:

```
my $twig = XML::Twig::XPath->new;
$twig->parse('your string');
my $nodes = $twig->findnodes('/Path/To/My/Node[ChildA="ValA" and ChildB="ValB" and ChildC="ValC"]');
print $nodes;
```

This prints "ValAValBValC".

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways to do this: by loading the whole XML and deleting the nodes you don't want, then outputting the twig, or by filtering as you go along, which is a little more complex but uses less memory.

The first way (you may need a recent version of XML::XPathEngine, I haven't tested it with older ones or with XML::XPath, which can also act as the XPath engine)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig::XPath;

my $t= XML::Twig::XPath->new( pretty_print => 'indented')
                       ->parse( \*DATA);
$_->delete for ($t->findnodes( '/Path/To/My/Node[./ChildA="ValA" and ./ChildB="ValB" and ./ChildC="ValC"]'));

$t->print;

__DATA__
<Path>
  <To>
    <My>
      <Node>
        <ChildA>ValA</ChildA>
        <ChildB>ValB</ChildB>
        <ChildC>ValC</ChildC>
      </Node>
      <Node>
        <ChildA>ValD</ChildA>
        <ChildB>ValB</ChildB>
        <ChildC>ValC</ChildC>
      </Node>
    </My>
  </To>
</Path>
```

And the "filter" way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { '/Path/To/My/Node' => \&filter },
                twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
                keep_spaces => 1,
              )
         ->parse( \*DATA);
exit;

# the handler expressions cannot lookahead, so we need to look at each node
# once it's completely parsed
sub filter
  { my( $t, $node)= @_;
    if(    ($node->field( 'ChildA') eq 'ValA')
        && ($node->field( 'ChildB') eq 'ValB')
        && ($node->field( 'ChildC') eq 'ValC')
      )
      { $node->delete; }
    else
      { $t->flush; }
  }

__DATA__
<Path>
  <To>
    <My>
      <Node>
        <ChildA>ValA</ChildA>
        <ChildB>ValB</ChildB>
        <ChildC>ValC</ChildC>
      </Node>
      <Node>
        <ChildA>ValD</ChildA>
        <ChildB>ValB</ChildB>
        <ChildC>ValC</ChildC>
      </Node>
    </My>
  </To>
</Path>
```